# longest run count program issue

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

Loop goes through an char array of a. Program should find the longest run of the given char.

The problem I have is that I always miss by 1 number or at least in this example.

I used the most common for loop with a[i]==ch && a[i+1]==ch to compare both numbers, if match found I do count++ in the instance where I have 3 consecutive characters it will only give me 2 since it compares with the i+1.

And I know I can't do a[i]==char because will not work as program purpose.

Can someone please help me how could I get that 3rd count on?
I am missing the logic here or something.

```
    char [] a = {'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'f'};
    char ch = 'a';
    int count = 0;
    int oneTime = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i<a.length; i++){
        System.out.print(a[i]);
        System.out.print(" ");
    }

    System.out.println(" ");

    for(int i = 0; i<a.length-1; i++){



        if(a[i]==ch && a[i+1]==ch){
            count++;

        }//end of if
        if(oneTime ==0)
            if(a[a.length-2]==a[a.length-1]){
                count++;
                oneTime++;
            }

    }

    System.out.print(count);

}

}
```

Comment: Did you account for the possibility that the longest run would be 1? or 0? A good way to check for logic errors is to say the pseudo code that you would use to do the problem. How will you count runs by iterating through the array? How will you keep track of the longest run?

Comment: For clarity, you are only looking for the longest run of a particular character, right?  (in this case the letter 'a')  You are not just trying to find the longest run of any character are you?

Comment: By the way, if an answer below is useful, there is a check-mark that marks the answer as "accepted".  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Standard mistake of counting comparisons instead of the characters.  Handle each character one at a time, and increment when it matches the designated character you are looking for.

```
char [] a = {'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'f'};
char ch = 'a';

for(int i = 0; i<a.length; i++){
    System.out.print(a[i]);
    System.out.print(" ");
}

System.out.println(" ");

int count = 0;
int largest = 0;
for(int i = 0; i<a.length; i++){

    if(a[i]==ch){
        count++;
    }
    else {
        count = 0;
    }
    //now remember if this is the longest span
    if (count > largest) {
        largest = count;
    }
}

System.out.print("The longest run is: "+largest);
```

That above will find the longest run of a specified character.

If you want to find the longest run of ANY character, try this:

```
char [] a = {'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'f'};
for(int i = 0; i<a.length; i++){
    System.out.print(a[i]);
    System.out.print(" ");
}

System.out.println(" ");

char ch = a[0];
int count = 1;
int largest = 1;
//note we skip the first character
for(int i = 1; i<a.length; i++){

    if(a[i]==ch){
        count++;
    }
    else {
        //reset with this char as first of a new run
        ch = a[i];
        count = 1;
    }
    //now remember if this is the longest span
    if (count > largest) {
        largest = count;
    }
}

System.out.print("The longest run is: "+largest);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int maxCount = 0;
int currentCount = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < a.length-1; i++){
   if(a[i] == a){
      currentCount++;
     if(maxCount < currentCount){
        maxCount = currentCount;
     }
   }
   else {
     currentCount = 0;
   }
}

System.out.print(maxCount);
```